# How to specify what base a string or number is in

Tags: javascript

So lets say I have the base 3 number 121 how would I specify that it was base 3.
Essentially I am looking for this:

```
let base_three = 121
console.log(base_three.toString(10))

output: 16
```

I am looking to convert a number from x base to x base and not just from x base to base 10

Comment: [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: You have the solutions below, but FYI `toString()` takes a radix argument but it's doing the conversion the opposite direction that you want: `Number(16).toString(3)` returns `121`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let i = parseInt("121", 3); console.log(i);`

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to turn it into a string and back into a number, parsing the string as base 3:

```
  parseInt(121 + "", 3) // 16
```

If you pass a number to parseInt, it will turn it into a string so you could also just do:

```
 parseInt(121, 3)
```

Comment: @milesZew well then call `.toString(toBase)` onto the result